# asp:Image not displaying within an asp:HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:Image inside an asp:HyperLink that's not being displayed. Here's the aspx.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlSubmitSrf" runat="server" Target="_blank">
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgSrf" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

And here's the codebehind. The Page_Init sets the hyperlink text, url, the image url, and the images's alt text.

```
        if (srf.Count > 0)
        {
            actionText = "View active SRF";
            hlSubmitSRF.Text = actionText;
            hlSubmitSRF.NavigateUrl = "SRF_Submit.aspx?SRF_ID=" + srf[0].Srf_id.ToString();                
            imageUrl = "images/Arrow_Right_Red.png";
        }
        else
        {
            actionText = "Submit SRF";
            hlSubmitSRF.Text = actionText;
            hlSubmitSRF.NavigateUrl = "SRF_Submit.aspx?APPID=" + app.Appid.ToString();                
            imageUrl = "images/Arrow_Right_Green.png";
        }

        imgSrf.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
        imgSrf.AlternateText = actionText;
```

If I move the image outside the asp:HyperLink, the image displays, so I know the path works. If I keep it inside the asp:HyperLink, the image doesn't even show up when I view page source.

Comment: When I set the imageurl on the aspx the image does display. But when I try to change it to something else in the codebehind then it doesn't. Is this something I'm not understanding with the page life cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
hlSubmitSRF.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
```

Set the ImageUrl on the HyperLink and don't put an `<asp:Image>` within the `<asp:HyperLink>`.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlSubmitSrf" runat="server" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>     

    if (srf.Count > 0)
    {
        actionText = "View active SRF";
        hlSubmitSRF.Text = actionText;
        hlSubmitSRF.NavigateUrl = "SRF_Submit.aspx?SRF_ID=" + srf[0].Srf_id.ToString();                
        hlSubmitSRF.ImageUrl = "images/Arrow_Right_Red.png";
    }
    else
    {
        actionText = "Submit SRF";
        hlSubmitSRF.Text = actionText;
        hlSubmitSRF.NavigateUrl = "SRF_Submit.aspx?APPID=" + app.Appid.ToString();                
        hlSubmitSRF.ImageUrl = "images/Arrow_Right_Green.png";
    }
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that I've tried this already. Setting the imageUrl on the hyperlink causes the hyperlink text to not show up. Apparently the image has precedence over the text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to use an image button?  I don't have the code in front of me, but the fields could be adjusted based on your conditions similar to the way you are using the hyperlink wrapper.

Comment: I considered it and may end up using this in case I can't get this method to work. I don't want to have a server side onClick event just to send the user to another page.

Comment: Maybe you could use two hyperlinks, make one visible on the first condition, or the second one visible on the second condition?  Maybe not the best coding practices but could help you display the image.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try not setting the hyperlink text in the page_init. Probably the .Text property replaces the image (or makes it invisible). The hyperlink also has a handy .ImageUrl property (as long as you do not use url routing).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can have both text and image in the asp:HyperLink control, however the following would work, like:

```
HtmlImage imgSrf = new HtmlImage();
HtmlAnchor hlSubmitSRF = new HtmlAnchor();
HtmlGenericControl hlSubmitSRFText = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
if (srf.Count > 0) {
    actiontext = "View active SRF";
    hlSubmitSRF.HRef = "SRF_Submit.aspx?SRF_ID=" + srf(0).Srf_id.ToString();
    imgSrf.Src = "images/Arrow_Right_Red.png";
} else {
    actiontext = "Submit SRF";
    hlSubmitSRF.HRef = "SRF_Submit.aspx?APPID=" + app.Appid.ToString();
    imgSrf.Src = "images/Arrow_Right_Green.png";
}
imgSrf.Alt = actiontext;
hlSubmitSRF.Controls.Add(imgSrf);
hlSubmitSRFText.InnerHtml = actiontext;
hlSubmitSRF.Controls.Add(hlSubmitSRFText);
ParentControl.Controls.Add(hlSubmitSRF);
```